# Reading specific data from file

Tags: c#, file

I want to read specific data from bat file (set values) and then write them into Textbox1.Text (these are first lines of file I want to read from) and I want to get values

XXXXX write to Textbox1.Text

YYYYY write to Textbox2.Text

ZZZZZ write to Textbox3.Text

SSSSS write to Textbox4.Text

```
   @echo off


   :::::: DANE LOGOWANIA DO BAZY DANYCH
   :: Baza danych
   set DB=XXXXX
   :: Serwer Bazy danych
   set DBServer=YYYYY
   :: Login do bazy danych
   set DBUser=ZZZZZ
   :: Hasło do bazy danych
   set DBPassword=SSSSS
```

Reading from file should be triggered from

```
   private void mssqlbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

   }
```

Then if someone change `Textbox1.Text` value it writes those values into file in the position it previously read from.

I've tried finding for a solution using regex, reading by lines but it doesn't work for me or I don't know at all how to do it.

To be precise, I'm just starting my adventure with C#, I'm not that familiar with it yet, so If you could explain to me as well instead of only providing a code I would be grateful :)

EDIT:
Actually it is not that small, whole bat file is like that:
http://wklej.to/sCQ6i
(I know bat file delete log file at the end but i will handle it)

And AppCode:
http://wklej.to/Z5IFd

Where in AppCode
`DBServerInput.Text was Textbox1.Text
DBInput.Text was Textbox2.Text
DBUserInput.Text was Textbox3.Text
DBPasswordInput was Textbox4.Texte`

Comment: Please share the code sample and the input data file. I guess you are not aware of the guidelines for using this forum.

Comment: why not serialize and de-serialize your data to and from an object? Makes it easier on many levels. Alternatively you have to open the file, read it all, modify what you want and then write it back to the file. Also another hint... take a look at the FileStream class in the System.IO namespace....

Comment: @Karan: I guess you don't know this isn't a forum ;)

Comment: Split your problem up in smaller steps. 1 - read file, 2 - parse lines, 3 - fill textboxes. Then to write it back, do the same but in reverse.

Answer (score 2):

So where did you get stuck? However, the first requirement is relative easy:

```
private void ButtonReadBatch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] linesToShowInTextBox = File.ReadLines(@"C:\Temp\batchTest.bat")
        .Select(l => l.Trim())
        .Where(l => l.StartsWith("set ", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && l.Contains('='))
        .Select(l => l.Split('=').Last().TrimStart())
        .ToArray();
    TextBox1.Lines = linesToShowInTextBox;
}
```

The second is more complicated, this should give you an idea. It's tested rudimentarily:

```
private void ButtonSumbitTextboxChangesToBatch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] lines = textBox1.Lines;
    if (lines.Length != 0)
    {
        int matchIndex = 0;
        var lineInfos = File.ReadLines(@"C:\Temp\batchTest.bat")
            .Select(l => l.Trim())
            .Select((line, index) => {
                bool isSetLine = line.StartsWith("set ", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && line.Contains('=');
                return new{ 
                    line, index, isSetLine,
                    setIndex = isSetLine ? matchIndex++ : -1 
                };
            });
        string[] newLines = lineInfos
            .Select(x => !x.isSetLine || x.setIndex >= lines.Length 
                ? x.line 
                : string.Format("set {0}={1}",
                    x.line.Split(' ')[1].Split('=')[0].Trim(),
                    lines[x.setIndex]))
            .ToArray();
        File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Temp\batchTest.bat", newLines);
    }
}
```

So don't use the `TextChanged` event but another button, otherwise the event is called on any change which causes undesired effects.

Comment: Plus one . I have no idea how to replace and re-write edited string to file. Your answer make me clear :)

Comment: @zey: there was a bug, the difficulty is to find the matching index since that is not the index of the line in the file but the "match-index". Now it should work, although i don't like to use the local variable in the LINQ query. If anyone has a better idea I would be very happy to hear it (of course, a plain loop maybe).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [System.IO.File-class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.file%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and its static Methods to read data from a file. Especially the Method *ReadAllLines* should help you. Thus, you can iterate over the lines or use an index to address. *foreach* and *for* loops should work.
The [String-class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) gives you the tools to deconstruct the data read, think of using the Methods *Split* or *IndexOf*.
Writing the data back to the file can also be done using the *System.IO.File*-class. The easiest way should be overwriting the complete file with all you values, since the amount of data is pretty low. Consider using the *AppendLine*-Method from the *System.IO.File*-class.

The given MSDN-Links should give you a good starting point for your research. I won't post code since you said you want to go onto the adventure for yourself ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm weak in Regular Expression , this code `string pattern = @"=(?<after>\w+)";` is to match the word after equal sign `=` , it's better if some experts show for a better way :D

```
      string txtBatFile= "<physical path for batfile>";
        if (File.Exists(txtBatFile))
        {
                 StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(txtBatFile);
                 string strFileText= SR.ReadToEnd();
                 SR.Close();
                 SR.Dispose();

        string pattern = @"=(?<after>\w+)";        

      MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(strFileText, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        ArrayList _strList = new ArrayList();
        foreach (Match match in matches)
       {
        _strList.Add(match.Groups["after"].ToString());
       }

        Textbox1.Text = _strList[0].ToString();
        Textbox2.Text = _strList[1].ToString();
        Textbox3.Text = _strList[2].ToString();
        Textbox4.Text = _strList[3].ToString();
        }
```

Comment: your code takes word with "=", like "=XXXXX" not only "XXXXX"